# How to create flyout effect using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

See: http://www.obout.com/flyout/flyout.aspx

How to create a flyout effect similar to the one shown in the page linked to above using jQuery?

Comment: You should accept some answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'transfer' effect in the jQuery UI effect-package: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/